# Weird error with non-ASCII character in CSH

Tags: csh

What is so special about the character "à" (a accent-grave) that makes the following assignement in CSH fail:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set title = `echo 'à'`
echo $title
```

It does NOT fail for any other character like: á, é, í, ó, ú, à, è, ì, ò, ù .... that I know of.

For example:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set title = `echo 'áéíóúèìòù'`
echo $title
```

works as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by fail?

Comment: `echo "$title"` worked for me, whereas without the dbl-quotes, the cmd hung.

Comment: For what it's worth, `echo "$title" | xxd` produces output of `00000000: c3a0 0a`. My guess is the unquoted version is being processed as a control char by whatever is supplying the `$TERM` functionality.

Comment: @Daniel A. White Just try it. The script will fail and you get "Killed" back after a longer period of time. With the other letters you get what is expected -- the character is echoed to the shell.

Comment: @shellter Yes, with the a-accent-grave it hungs, but it works fine with any other acceted letter.

Comment: *"but it works fine..."*. Yes, you have said so in your O.P. Can't you work with `echo "$title"` ? Then "problem solved!" (-;! .... All shells wind up (at one point or another) creating problems with unquoted variables. If you need a fix for this, then you'll have to do the deep research to see why your code is jamming up. (Does this do the same thing inside a `cron` based process? If not, then that again points to the `$TERM` environment (and those sub-systems that provide it).)
There is an env var that European users prepend to cmds using non-ascii 255 chars. Can't think of it right now.

Comment: Ah yes, read about [locales in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/set-system-locales-in-linux/). When I test in my environment, running the cmd `locales` produces `LANG=C.UTF-8` and a bunch of others standard in a US based machine. I do notice at the end of that output that `LC_ALL=` (empty). Maybe these will give you clues to search for your environment. OR at least update your Q with the output of `locales`. Good luck.

Comment: Did some tests to isolate what might be failing. Your most basic test (after similar setup) does work in bash` (Ver '5.0.17(1)-release'):   `echo $title` produces the correct output BUT your follow up, produces `áCíóúèìòù` . I did a test of `stty -a > bash_stty_cfg` and under `csh` ... `stty -a > csh_stty_cfg` but there was no differences in the files. I'm out of ideas. Hopefully a true `LANG=C.UTF-8` guru will know what the problem is. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, there is nothing special about the character of "à" it is a standard unicode character like the others you mentioned, chances are the problem persists with your version of shell or the way the locale settings are configured

but if you're looking to fix the issue try this code which displays the same character through the octal representation

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set title = `echo '\205'`
echo $title
```

Comment: using your code in the `csh`  available  in MS WSL returns `\205`. What is your OS? (`uname -srv`)

Comment: Your answer contains a contradiction -- if there is nothing special about the character `à` why would you need to use octal representation for this character and not the others. On top of that your code outputs `\205` and not `à` like it is desirable.